# simple equation solve

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have got this :

```
price  = 300

p = newPrice - (price+170+newPrice*0.02+(newPrice*0.01)+25)
```

How would I solve newPrice so **p = 100** ?

Thank you in advance ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the new price be $q$.

Then $100=q-(300+170+0.02q+0.01q+25)=q-(495+0.03q)=0.97q-495$.

Hence $0.97q=595$ so $q=\frac{595\times 100}{97}=613.40$ to $2$ decimal places.